# Webpack treeshaking with ~/components/ui/index.js and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, tree-shaking

Hello I have a index in a UI module within my components exporting all components in that folder like so:

`~/components/ui/index.js`:

```
import Button from './Button';
import Footer from './Footer';

export { Button, Footer }
```

And I use it in some page like so:

```
import { Button } from '~/components/ui';

export default {
  components: {
     Button,
     Footer: () => import('~/components/ui/Footer')
  }
}
```

Now ideally, the Footer component should be split in a different chunk, and only be loaded if needed. This works if I remove it from the exports of `~/components/ui/index.js`, like so:

`~/components/ui/index.js`:

```
import Button from './Button';
//import Footer from './Footer'; 

export { Button, /*Footer*/ }
```

Now this works. But I would like to keep it in the index. And use webpack treeshaking to eliminate the `Footer` from the default bundle.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This might be a configuration problem. Have you properly set `sideEffects: false` in your package.json. Note also that tree shaking will be active in production mode. In development mode, unused parts of your code will be marked as `unused` but not removed. https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: @Saraband Yes, I am testing it in production mode. Do I need to specify a package.json for the `~/components/ui` folder with `sideEffects: false`?

Comment: In the main `package.json` of your project you can specify the property `sideEffects` (which can be either a boolean or an array of string) [to mark files that are safe to prune if unused](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free). So in your case you can mark `"sideEffects": [ "./components/ui/*"]` so the compiler knows any file from `./components/ui` are safe to be tree shaked